# Contents of Memory at very small Addresses

Tags: operating-system, memory-address

can someone please tell me what contents does the memory have at very small Addresses(0-100), such as address 7 for example in a Linux-based operating system such as CentOS and in Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Low Virtual Addresses**

For most operating systems, at least the lower half of a virtual address space depends on the process it belongs to (with "kernel space" in the upper portion). Typically, to catch dodgy pointers (which includes things like "`int pointer = NULL; foo = pointer[1234];`" and "`struct myStructure *pointer = NULL; foo = pointer->myField;`"; where the address that's accessed isn't the address that the pointer points to) the lowest virtual addresses are reserved for literally nothing; so that if any software tries to access it the CPU generates a page fault to inform the kernel that software tried to do something very wrong.

**Low Physical Addresses**

What is at low physical addresses depend on which type of computer it is (80x86, ARM, MIPs, ...) and what the firmware is (e.g. BIOS, UEFI) and other factors (how the chipset was configured). Without this information there can't be a specific answer (the only possible answer is "nobody can know").